# How to store the previous value of a user in a loop?

Tags: java, swing, variables, do-while

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Hello {

    public static int s1;

    public static void main(String [] args){

            userInput();
    }

    public static void userInput() {

        do {
            String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer. Enter 0 to quit. ");

            s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);

            if (s1 == 0)
                break;

        } while (s1 > 0);

    }
}
```

I want to find the greatest number from the user input. How to store the previous values of the user's input in a do-while loop?

Thank you!

Comment: If this is a homework-type assignment, then good practice would be to give your variables (s1, str1) meaningful names. s1 and str1 are vague and could be confused with other values in a larger program.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is probably this:

```java
public static void userInput() {

  do {
    String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer. Enter 0 to quit. ");

    // s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1); // don't save directly to this variable
    int newValue = Integer.parseInt(str1);
    if (newValue > s1) {
      s1 = newValue;
    }

    if (newValue == 0)
      break;

  } while (s1 > 0); 

}
```

A quick note: the `while(s1 > 0)` check isn't really doing anything here. Since you have the break statement above, you can simplify this to `while(true)`

Comment: The value of s1 is not assigned. How can we use (newValue > s1) as a condition?

Comment: You can give it an initial value outside of the expected range -- you noted that you wanted positive integers only, so a negative number would work. In a situation where all values were possible, you'd probably instead use the `Integer` class directly, and set the initial value to null.

Answer (score 0):

When saving numbers, you have to be careful not to lose them. Imagine for a minute that you've purchased a lottery ticket using your lucky numbers. Later in the week, when the drawing happens, your lucky numbers are the winner! You go to find your ticket but...what's that? You can't remember where you put it? Well what's a few hundred million, right?

Did you see where you went wrong? It wasn't remembering the numbers. It was remembering where you put the numbers! You don't want to lose them. So the first thing you need to do is save your numbers to a file, like this:

```
String filename = "your_filename.txt";
FileWriter file = null;
BufferedWriter writer = null;

try
{
    file = new FileWriter(filename);
    writer = new BufferedWriter(file);

    do {
        String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer. Enter 0 to quit. ");

        s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
        writer.write(Integer.toString(str1));
        writer.newLine();

        if (s1 == 0)
            break;

    } while (s1 > 0);

    writer.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    // Common practice is to ignore exceptions since they probably won't happen
}
```

So now you've got a file to save your numbers, but what if you have a hard drive failure? Or your computer gets stolen? Or you download a virus while playing illegal foreign online lotteries? You're going to want to back it up. A common service for doing just that is S3.

After including the S3 library for Java and initializing your S3 client, add the following code.

```
String bucketName = "important-numbers";
File localNumbers = new File(filename);
s3client.putObject(bucketName, filename, localNumbers);
```

Congrats! Now for a nominal fee (don't worry your lottery winnings will more than cover), you'll never lose your numbers again.